# Mono binary can't find DLLs in subdirectory

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I'm using Mono's mcs on Ubuntu. I have a Monogame program that has to locate the Monogame libraries in a subdirectory called "libs". It compiles fine, but when it comes to runtime it gives me an error saying it can't find it.

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MonoGame.Framework, Version=3.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
>   File name: 'MonoGame.Framework, Version=3.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
>   [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MonoGame.Framework, Version=3.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
>   File name: 'MonoGame.Framework, Version=3.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

My compiler flags are as follows:

```
mcs -r:libs/MonoGame.Framework.dll -target:winexe -out:main.exe *.cs
```

Not even a warning from the compiler, but it can't run. I've tried a lot of variations of these flags and I can't find an option to static compile (and I don't really want to).
It runs fine when the libraries are in the same directory, but in a subdirectory it doesn't work. I've tried supposed solutions such as "AppDomain.CurrentDomain" and "Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable" but that didn't work and honestly it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subdirectory is not going to be part of the search path. If you must put it in a subdirectory, I would recommend that you solve this with an application config file which [specifies a private search path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348197/how-to-properly-access-the-privatebinpath-property-of-the-current-appdomain):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="libs" />
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What do I do with this? Can I use this outside of an IDE? I'm using the command line.

Comment: App config files don't have anything to do with the IDE. It is just a file named `yourapp.exe.config`

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much. Boy that sure was not as straight forward as other languages.